# Finding closest product of two pairs of variables in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I have four variables, for instance, a, b,c,d

- a,c are double
- b,d are integer
- a != c

for simplicity, lets assume a=59.8, c=22

I'm trying to find if there is  a*b - c*d = 0 and when that happens, what is the value of b,d.Or when a*b - c*d is not possible 0, find b,d when a*b - c*d has smallest value.

Is there an algorithm to do it? I'm hoping to solve it in Java.

Comment: Not following, are `a,b,c,d` all given? Should the `ab` - be one double one integer, or all goes?

Comment: originally, a,b,c,d are variables, the a,c are constantly changing. a,c are double

Comment: and is ac-bd also a valid solution? In any case the number of such pairs is really low, you can just check all of them and get the best result

Comment: hmm, i certainly can check them if there is limited number of pairs, but a,c are changing constantly, which gives unlimited number of pairs....thats the reality. ideally, assuming a,c not changing, then i can manually check

Comment: Actually it's an linear function a = cd/b. There's an infinite number of solutions with such a loose constraints.

Comment: I guess we should be considering `|ab-cd|` instead of `ab-cd`. Otherwise `b = 0` and `d = Integer.MIN_VALUE * Integer.signum(c)` is an obvious but fairly ininteressant solution.

Comment: good point, i should go with |ab-cd|

Comment: Can u provide more context? You seem to have some changing variables - what means constantly changing?

Comment: For instance for d=1 and b=1 the solution is a = c, any pair of equal doubles.

Comment: ok, i edited my original post and lets assume a,c are fixed for now

Comment: @Tunaki, multiplying `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.signum` is quite meaningless as `-Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: what are the inputs and what are the outputs ???

Comment: peeps vote this Q down, it doesn't even describe the problem coherently....

Comment: on hold !!!! muhahahah

Comment: @gen-y-s if you don't understand, there are others who may understand the question. no need to accuse and being aggressive, PLEASE, and thx for participating anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assume without loss of generality (yes really) that `a` and `c` are integers (not `int`s but actual integers) as well.

The equation `a * b = c * d` where `a` and `c` are constants is easy to solve, pick `b = c` and
`d = a`, now both sides of the equation are  `a * c`.

What if `a` or `c` is not an integer? No problem, just scale them by a power of two. They're doubles, so it's guaranteed that there is a power of two that scales them both to integers (a double is an integer scaled by some power of two). Now we have

```
(a * p) * b = (c * q) * d
```

where `p` and `q` are powers of two such that `a * p` is an integer and `c * q` is an integer.

Pick `b = c * q`, `d = a * p`, and it's same on both sides again. And obviously you can roll those extra factors into `b` and `d`, just reassociate the multiplications.

Comment: Maths epic win. Lovely solution!

Comment: do you mean (a^p)*b=(c^q)*d?  I'm not quite clear about scale a double to integer part, 59.3232^2= 3.5192e+03, how could  3.5192e+03 be an integer?

Comment: You are not accounting for overflow. Doubles (IEEE) are 8-byte, with a 6.5-byte mantissa; while Java ints are 4-byte. Therefore, scaling a double is not guaranteed to return its mantissa. Longs (8-byte) can still overflow due to multiplications. You may need to use `BigInteger` to avoid running into such issues at all.

Comment: @user1225072 no `p` and `q` will be powers themselves, but then just multiply by them. For example, double(59.3232) = 8348998169200794 * (2^-47) (note that this does not equal 59.3232)

Comment: @tucuxi that's why I said "not `int`s" in the beginning

Comment: @harold  ok i think i got what u meant now, very smart way of doing it,  but in this case how do i find  8348998169200794 * (2^-47) dynamically ? i still have to manually do it? maybe there is a library in java that does it?

Comment: @user1225072 you can use `doubleToRawLongBits` and then extract the exponent and significand (they're stored in a funny way though, so watch out) then optionally throw away trailing zeroes (I could have removed one more here).

Comment: @harold tested work, thanks a lot.